# I have had cancer

Tags: meaning

If I currently have cancer I'd say: "I have cancer".

If I have had cancer for two years, I have had cancer for two years, but if I "have had" cancer at any point in my life "I have had cancer", but it doesn't necessarily mean I have cancer now, correct?

Example: "Travel insurance for people who have or have had cancer."

Comment: What else would it mean in that sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV I am not sure if it means that you have had cancer for a while, even if you don't add a duration.

Comment: Why would someone write “have or have had cancer” if they only mean people that currently have cancer? I’m not trying to pick on you, I’m trying to understand the reasons for your uncertainty.

Comment: @ ColleenV I appreciate that. So if someone has had cancer at some point in their lives, but they don't have it now, I can say that they have had cancer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

I can say *I have had leukaemia for five years* because I still have it.

But I would not normally say *I have had leukaemia* because I still have it.

The difference is the *for*. The first means "over the whole of a period lasting five years_, and because of the perfect construction, that period is understood to extend to the present.

The second means "at some time during an unspecified period that extends to the present", but implies that it did not last over the whole of that period, and in particular it did not last until the present, or I would have used a different form.

Comment: @ Colin Fine "what different form would you have used? "I have leukemia" or "I've had leukemia for 5 years"?

Comment: @anouk: exactly. Either of those

Comment: If you had just recovered from the flu for example, you are no longer ill, would you say "I have been ill"?

Comment: That's right, @anouk

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption.

If you had cancer for a period of time in the past, but no longer do, and you wanted to describe how long you had it, you would just use a *simple past* construction:

> I had cancer for five years.

Or without mentioning the time-frame you could just say:

> I had cancer.

Or, to emphasize the fact that you no longer have it:

> I used to have cancer